# SimpleSymbols String in java

Tags: java, string

I am a beginner in java, and I have this question:

**Write a java program that include method SimpleSymbols(str) take the str parameter being passed and determine if it is an acceptable sequence by either returning the string true or false. The str parameter will be composed of + and = symbols with several letters between them (i.e. ++d+===+c++==a) and for the string to be true each letter must be surrounded by a + symbol.**

Sample Test Cases:

Input:" +d+=3=+s+ "

Output:"true"  //as +d+ and +s+ are surrounded by +

Input:" f++d+ "

Output:"false" // as f+ is not surround by +

---

here is my code:

```
package simplesympoles;


import java.util.Scanner;
public class SimpleSympoles {
    static Scanner input= new Scanner(System.in);
    public static void main(String[] args) {


    for (int i = 0; i <2; i++) {
        System.out.println("Enter a string: ");
    String  s=input.next();
    System.out.println(SimpleSymbols(s));
    }


}


public static boolean SimpleSymbols(String s){

    String s1=s.trim();

    for (int i = 0 ; i <s.length(); i++) 
        if (s1.charAt(i+1)=='+'&&s1.charAt(i-1)=='+' && Character.isLetter(s1.charAt(i)))
            return true;

return false;

}

}
```

when I enter the string which is make the method returns true, it runs good, but when I enter a string that does not detect the conditions, it does not return false, but a run time error happen and I tried my best to fix it but I can't

here is my run:

> Enter a string:
>
> +d+=3=+s+
>
> true
>
> Enter a string:
>
> f++d+
>
> Exception in thread "main"
>
> java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range:
>
> -1    at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:658)     at simplesympoles.SimpleSympoles.SimpleSymbols(SimpleSympoles.java:26)
>
> at simplesympoles.SimpleSympoles.main(SimpleSympoles.java:14)
>
> /Users/Zahraa_maher/Library/Caches/NetBeans/8.2/executor-snippets/run.xml:53:
>
> Java returned: 1 BUILD FAILED (total time: 21 seconds)

I need your assistance to solve it, and thank you very much!

Comment: You have several logical errors. If the second character is a `+`, then it will throw (Test: `=+====`). If the first letter is surrounded by `+`, it will return true, no matter if the other letters are surrounded (Test: `+a+===b=`). If the last letter is checked, it will throw.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn Kuhn I don't understand, if you can show me by the code I will be thankful for you

Comment: nuff with the negs, ppl are learning and yes they are confused - no reason to kill their enthusiasm. Go for it @Zehraa you will learn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With this test:

```
if (s1.charAt(i+1)=='+'&&s1.charAt(i-1)=='+' && Character.isLetter(s1.charAt(i)))
        return true;
```

You're saying that if you find a letter with a `+` symbol either side then the string is valid. But *every* letter has to be surrounded by a `+`, so you need to switch the logic and instead do

```
if (Character.isLetter(s1.charAt(i)) && (s1.charAt(i-1)!='+' || s1.charAt(i+1)!='+'))
        return false;
```

Then, if you get to the end of the string without returning false you know the string is valid and you can return true.

Also, if you want to look behind and ahead one character then you can't start at the first character or go to the last character, or you'll get a `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException`. Instead your loop should look like this:

```
for (int i = 1 ; i <s.length()-1; i++)
```

Obviously you do need to check the first and last characters, but we can do that right at the start, since if either of them is a letter then the string is invalid.

```
if(Character.isLetter(s1.charAt(0)) || Character.isLetter(s1.charAt(s1.length()-1)))
    return false;
```

Putting this all together we get:

```
public static boolean SimpleSymbols(String s){
  String s1=s.trim();

  if(Character.isLetter(s1.charAt(0)) || Character.isLetter(s1.charAt(s1.length()-1)))
      return false;

  for (int i = 1 ; i <s.length()-1; i++) 
      if (Character.isLetter(s1.charAt(i)) && (s1.charAt(i-1)!='+' || s1.charAt(i+1)!='+'))
          return false;

  return true;
}
```

Comment: Thank you sooo much! your explanation assist me to be well-understand!
thank you again! <3

Answer (score 0):

finally, I got the answer!

```
package simplesympoles;


import java.util.Scanner;
public class SimpleSympoles {
    static Scanner input= new Scanner(System.in);
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        for (int i = 0; i <2; i++) {
            System.out.println("Enter a string: ");
        String  s=input.next();
        System.out.println(SimpleSymbols(s));
        }


    }


    public static boolean SimpleSymbols(String s){

        String s1=s.trim();

        if(Character.isLetter(s.charAt(0)) || Character.isLetter(s.charAt(s.length()-1)))
            return false;

        for(int i=1;i<s.length();i++){
            if(Character.isLetter(s.charAt(i)) && (s.charAt(i-1)!='+' || s.charAt(i+1)!='+'))
                return false;
        }

        return true;
}

}
```

Comment: The test in the `for` loop should be `i<s.length()-1` otherwise you'll get a `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` if the string ends with a letter. Compare with the code in my answer.